# which size of struct member alignment in VC bring performance benefit?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction, cpu, alignment

does struct member alignment in VC bring performance benefit? if it is what is the best performance implication by using this and **which size** is best for current cpu architecture (x86_64, SSE2+, ..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perf takes a nose-dive on x86 and x64 cores when a member straddles a cache line boundary.  The common compiler default is 8 byte packing which ensures you're okay on long long, double and 64-bit pointer members.

SSE2 instructions require an alignment of 16, the code will bomb if it is off.  You cannot get that out of a packing pragma, the heap allocator for example will only provide an 8-byte alignment guarantee.  Find out what your compiler and CRT support.  Something like __declspec(align(16)) and a custom allocator like _aligned_malloc().  Or over-allocate the memory and tweak the pointer yourself.

Comment: It's not just about crossing cache-line boundaries.  If your 32-bit int isn't aligned to a 4-byte boundary, there will still be a perf hit even if it's within the cache line.  The compiler generally pads elements to start on a multiple of their size (up to 8 bytes).  That's not to say it'll pad everything to 8-byte boundaries.  With the compiler's default packing, an built-in type will always be appropriately aligned.  If you have an array of structs, some of the array elements may cross a cache-line boundary, but none of the individual members will.

Answer (score 0):

The default alignment used by the compiler should be appropriate for the target platform (32- or 64-bit Intel/AMD) for general data.  To take advantage of SIMD, you might have to use a more restrictive alignment on those arrays, but that's usually done with a `#pragma` or special data type that applies just to the data you'll be using in the SIMD instructions.

Comment: which size of alignment is the best fit to use SIMD instruction?

Comment: 16. __declspec( align( 16 ) ), or directly use __m128i.